# Making "Countif" worksheet function variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that counts the cell in a range if there's a number. The total number of cell counted will then be shown in row 3. My issue now is that the formula is not variable and I have no idea how to make it too.
If I enter this code, row 3 reports all the same result (which is from the first column of data). Hoping somebody can help me here!!

```
Sub Six_Continue()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastClm As Long


    With ActiveSheet
        LastClm = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(3, LastClm))
        Rng.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C5", "C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row), "<>?")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you know that COUNT counts only numbers while COUNTA counts numbers and text?

Comment: Yup I do. The count function works fine for my worksheet, I just can't seem to get the range to move on to the next column!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CountIf` will count cells even if they don't contain a number. Using `Count` ensures that only cells containing numbers are taken into account.

```
Sub Six_Continue()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastClm As Long
    Dim myClm As Long


    With ActiveSheet
        LastClm = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For myClm = 1 To LastClm
            Set Rng = .Cells(3, myClm)
            Rng.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(.Cells(5, myClm), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, myClm).End(xlUp).Row, myClm)))
        Next myClm
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks so much!!

Maybe I didn't specify, but the numbers in my range were as a result of an array formula. That's why I used countif and <>?

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified version:

```
Sub Six_Continue()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim LastClm As Long, i As Long
LastClm = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LastClm
    Cells(3, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(2, i)), "<>?")
Next
End Sub
```